# getting an external ip address on a LAN pc through proxy

Tags: proxy, ip, remote

My office computer works on local office LAN and has ip address like 10.12.133.45. 
i can access the internet through the office proxy(when i got to a site like whatismyip.com it shows the proxy ip)

I often need access to my office pc at home(even a command prompt access is enough). i thought of setting up netcat but since i dont have a unique external ip it is not possible to conect from home

is there any way out? since i can access internet from office pc. is there any online service which can assign an ip once you connect

Note1: i dont want my pc running all day and it gets a dynamic ip each time i boot so i dont want to connect from office to home

Note2: i dont want to run teamviewer

Note3:I dont have any restrictions from system admin or anyone about connecting from home its just that i need a way out

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [LogMeIn](https://secure.logmein.com/).

Comment: +1 I have used LogMeIn Free for over two years and it's very simple to use.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider setting up [Hamachi](http://hamachi.cc), which would give your PC an extra IP address which is reachable from anywhere else you have Hamachi installed (at home), then you're free to use any remote control program (e.g. [UltraVNC](http://uvnc.com) (or any other VNC app, but UltraVNC is supposed to be good over the internet), RDP, a telnet or ssh server).

Comment: will try that out....thanks
i dont need desktop sharing and other stuff just a command prompt

Answer (score 0):

The proxy/firewall at your work would need to be configured to allow a connection from the internet on a specific port to be forwarded to your work pc.  This sort of configuration would allow you to use the remote connection technology of your choice, IE windows RDP, telnet etc.

There are services that allow remote control of windows (not sure about the complete list of supported OSes, I'm all windows) machines from any other PC with an internet connection.  They work through NAT gateways and normally through firewalls and proxies as well but they require an agent running on the PC that will be controlled remotely and depend on a third party server to maintain the connection.  LogMeIn and GotoMyPC are the two services I have personally used.  I'm sure there are others.

Answer (score 0):

Note3:I dont have any restrictions from system admin....
If this is true, then tweak your Proxy server at work to assign a NAT to your machine MAC id like pipTheGeek advise (in one way or another) and you can choose almost any remote control application out there.
But your work place network admin might be giving you the run around. Even I can grant you unrestricted access from your home network. But entry into the office network is another story. Net admins tend to give run arounds because they don't like confrontations. Push them too far, though, and you will experience a mysterious phenomenon called packet droppings.